# eMMC initialisation questions about CMD line and its handshake commands

Tags: cortex-m, nxp, emmc

I'm trying to a new board working that has an eMMC connected to an iMX RT1062 via a multipelxer.

On the previous board, without a multiplexer it worked, but I don't have one of these boards to compare with.

All documentation I've come across talks about starting with CMD0 and how you can send an argument of 0 or 0xFFFFFFFA. When I step through the code, it looks like (in the code) CMD0 is 0 and the argument is 0 and there should be no reply. However, the scope tells me something quite different.

The NXP BSP that provides the software used on the micro is really hard to follow, but it *does* look like the command that it's set up to send for CMD0 is 0. So it looks to me like it's sending a command of 0 and an argument of 0. I have searched high and low on the web and can find nothing that lists the commands. Naively I assumed they'd be in the eMMC datasheet, but no.

So, first question is what *is* CMD0 and what is its length? Below is what I see on the scope when I step over the command to send out CMD0 go idle. Does this trace look correct for CMD0?

It has a slightly weird 69 clock pulses which I find highly suspicious.

[image: Scope Trace]

Second Question is is there a list of these commands anywhere? Including, especially, what you should see being sent out and how long the command is. I can see a list of what the length of, for example, the returned CSD data should be, but not the command itself and any argument that might have to go with it.

Third Question regards the fact that there is a TSA27518E that is switching the I/O from the micro to either an SD card, or this eMMC device. I can see that traffic is getting between the two. It looks identical on both sides of the multiplexer. The clock is only 387kHz so it's crawling. (There is a 4k7 pullup on the CMD line on the eMMC side of the multiplexer).

The real issue here comes when the value for CID and CSD registers are requested. The values returned for CID are wrong and those for CIS are not returned at all. This makes me think that commands being sent out are wrong, but this is identical software to the previous, working board, which suggests an issue with the multiplexer.

Final question: Is it possible this multiplexer is causing an issue? I don't really see why it would. It's a bidirectional multiplexer, and while the initial handshaking is taking place it's very low speed.

Comment: If the eMMC is an industry standard, the commands are found in a JEDEC JESD84-B51 (it is paywalled)

Comment: I've seen that document and it doesn't tell you what any of the CMDx commands actually are. All it mentions are the arguments you can send for some of them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the data on your scope is indeed CMD0 with arg 0.
Here is the same CMD0 I captured with my logic analyzer:

[image]

> Second Question is is there a list of these commands anywhere? Including, especially, what you should see being sent out and how long the command is.

The command dataframe is 48 bits long.
Look for a table named "Command Format" in the JEDEC JESD84-B51 document you have. It explains everything.

Detailed description of CMDs are in a section called "Detailed command description"

The number x in CMDx dataframe are literally just, number. (bit [45:40], 6 bit wide so totally 63 CMDs)
All related behaviors when the eMMC chips receive CMDx are hard coded in the chip.

Here are some other examples for you:

CMD1
[image]

CMD6
[image]

> Final question: Is it possible this multiplexer is causing an issue?

Unfortunately, I have no experiences regarding multiplexers so I couldn't really help, but I'll suggest checking if the I/O voltage to the eMMC is correct.
eMMCs have a power input called *Vccq* and the voltage on Vccq is used for reference to determine if it received a 1 or a 0.

So if I were you I'll start by checking if the I/O voltages match Vccq voltage.